# como puedo hacer un programa que convierta una cadena de caracteres de minúsculas a mayúsculas y viceversa, (es para eclipse)

Tags: eclipse

Realizar un programa que convierta una cadena de caracteres de minúsculas a mayúsculas, y viceversa, según la opción elegida por el usuario[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenida. ¿Qué intentaste? No damos mentorías. Si tu IDE no te muestra sugerencias de las operaciones que puedes ejecutar sobre los objetos, en la documentación de [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) puedes encontrar un par de funciones que te serán útiles (`toLowerCase` y `toUpperCase`). La clase [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) también tiene 2 funciones llamadas así.

Comment: Hola Katy, bienvenida, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, resuélvanlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema,

Comment: mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.